# Infinite scroll with Angularjs and Mongoose - performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a list of images that I get with Angular using `$http.get()` from MongoDB using Mongoose and Expressjs.

What I did works fine but I have a doubt about performance.

So far I found two ways to do it:

- using `skip`
- using `$nin`

The queries looks like this:

```
    // Using $nin:
    var skip = req.query.skip || [];

    User.find({ _id : { $nin: skip }})
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .limit(15)
    .exec(function(err, users) {
    if (err) res.json({ 'msg': 'Error loading users' });
    res.json({
      users: users
    });
  });
```

and:

```
    // Using skip
    User.find({})
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .skip(15)
    .limit(15)
    .exec(function(err, users) {
    if (err) res.json({ 'msg': 'Error loading users' });
    res.json({
      users: users
    });
  });
```

Googleling around it seems like using `skip` lack of performance after a while...

But looking at the `$nin` option I found after scrolling and scrolling a very long query... with plenty of `_id`...

**Which of the 2 solution should be better to use?**

**Or there is a third way much better than those, maybe I'm doing something wrong?**

Thanks

Comment: You can also use `lean()` option to reduce time that it takes mongoose to build the model with all of it's methods etc. IMO the `skip` option is better here (that's how I implement my paging solutions and never ran into any problems)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about `lean()` and write a working example please? The documentation for `lean()` lack of every kind of information. Thanks.

Comment: `lean` option tells mongoose to not include it's methods to the results, so you won't be able to use mongoose on the results you will get. You can use it like this: `User.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(15).limit(15).lean().exec(...)`. It will reduce the time it takes to get the results from db and will act almost as fast as the native mongo client

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin `.lean()` has nothing to do with this. Please do not make misleading comments.

Comment: Using `.skip(15).limit(15)` seems that it doesn't work properly... I see always duplications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you want to use [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) with a list of previously seen `_id` values but combine that with a [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) or [**`$lte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) (depending on order) operator on something you are sorting on.

This is generally the case for most "otherwise sorted queries", but in the case where the `_id` field is the one you are sorting on ( and in decending order ) it just becomes a matter of working with [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) to find values that are less than the "last seen value" from the previous page.

So when iterating, store the "last seen value" from the last item in your "page limit" results, then use the [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operator in subsequent queries:

ie:

```
var lastSeen = null; // declare in a global or session or something

User.find({})
    .sort({ "_id": -1 })
    .limit(15)
    .exec(function(err,docs) {
        lastSeen = docs.slice(-1).id;
    });
```

And then:

```
User.find({ "_id": { "$lt": lastSeen })
    .sort({ "_id": -1 })
    .limit(15)
    .exec(function(err,docs) {
        lastSeen = docs.slice(-1).id;
    });
```

Comment: What about the infinite query Angular send to the server?

Comment: What is an "infinite query"? Simple parameter here in a "single" lastSeen value, being the "last" in the list that was displayed. 1-5 -> then( > 5 ) = 6 - 10 -> then ( > 10 ) = 10 - 15 and so on. Not hard.

Comment: not hard but I'm a noob trying to learn... Implementing this code I receive no data at the beginning...

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo Slow down a little. "No data from the beginning"? The query object is blank at the begining. So you retrieve everything and just limit to 15 results after sorting in reverse. Somewhere, even in the server side or the client, you want to pay attention to the last `_id` value seen in those results. Then in your "getMoreResults" call, you want to pass that value into the query. Since you are sorting in reverse you use the `$lt` ( or "less than" ) operator as shown. This is basic concept of "forward paging". Where you are retrieving based on the next highest value from the last seen.

Comment: Got it. Thanks it worked fine and I hope it will be fine with a big amount of data in terms of performance.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo Beats the pants off of `.skip()` and `.limit()`. The only limitation is where you want page references such as `1..2..3..4..etc` as links in controls. Then "skip" and "limit" are your only option.

Comment: Sorry if i come back to this but: there is a way to don't repeat the query? I mean: `User.find( {_id: {'$lt': lastSeen}} || {_id: {'$ne': ''}})`, something like that...